# fgets(): Ok by console, Bad by pipe

Tags: c, linux, io, pipe

Executing the following C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char stdinput[10];
  while (1) {
    fgets(stdinput, 10, stdin);
    fputs(stdinput, stdout);
  }
}
```

produces:

**By console:**

```
./a.out
input
input
```

and then it waits for more input. That is, it echoes stdin to stdout, similarly to `cat`.

**By pipe:**

```
echo input | ./a.out
input
input
input
[...]
```

after being started, it floods the console, all by itself, without interaction.

This example program is exactly what I used for the tests; it's not a cut.
I would expect the two tests to behave the same way. What's happening?

Comment: Once again a perfect demonstration why unguarded input operations are always an error... you must *never* ignore the result of an input operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once `EOF` is reached, `fgets` returns NULL immediately without waiting for input (or modifying the buffer). Thus, it will loop infinitely. In your pipe case, `echo` will close the pipe once it has written `"input\n"`, resulting in EOF.

Change your `fgets` call to

```
if(fgets(stdinput, 10, stdin) == NULL)
    break;
```

Answer (score 6):

You could just replace your loop condition by your `fgets` call, giving:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char stdinput[10];
  while (fgets(stdinput, 10, stdin)) {
    fputs(stdinput, stdout);
  }
}
```

This will loop until you get an EOF, in which case `fgets()` returns NULL just as [@nneonneo said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12527096/294313). But with this condition you will not have to break your `while()`.

Answer (score 1):

[**Note**: solves the wrong problem.]

See http://sweslo17.blogspot.tw/2012/04/c-standard-input-redirection.html.

After `fgets()`, you can add below code to restore `stdin` again that resolve pipe problems.

```
freopen("/dev/tty","rb",stdin);
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't look like it solves the right problem.  However, I've cleaned it up to show you how I would have liked it to look if it *did* solve the correct problem.